# Fonts are not loaded when UI Kitten wants to use them in React Native project

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I am using the [UI Kitten](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/) library in a `React Native` project with `Typescript`.
I've created a `mapping.json` and a `react-native.config.js` file which look like this:

- `mapping.json`:

  ```
  {
     "strict": {
        "text-font-family": "OpenSans-Regular",

        "text-heading-1-font-size": 30,
        "text-heading-1-font-weight": "800",
        "text-heading-1-font-family": "OpenSans-Bold",

        "text-subtitle-1-font-size": 15,
        "text-subtitle-1-font-weight": "600",
        "text-subtitle-1-font-family": "OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic",

        "text-paragraph-1-font-size": 12,
        "text-paragraph-1-font-weight": "400",
        "text-paragraph-1-font-family": "OpenSans-Light",

        "text-caption-1-font-size": 12,
        "text-caption-1-font-weight": "400",
        "text-caption-1-font-family": "OpenSans-Regular",

        "text-label-font-size": 12,
        "text-label-font-weight": "800",
        "text-label-font-family": "OpenSans-SemiboldItalic"
     }
  }
  ```
- `react-native.config.js:`

  ```
   module.exports = {
     project: {
     ios: {},
     android: {},
     },
     assets: ['./assets/fonts'],
   };
  ```

My custom fonts are located under the `assets/fonts` folder and I've executed the `npx react-native link` command.

I am getting the following error message:
[image]

If I click on `Dismiss` the application is working correctly I think the fonts are not loaded only when the application starts.

I tried loading the fonts like this in my `App.tsx`, didn't help:

```
 const App = (): JSX.Element => {
 const [assetsLoaded, setAssetsLoaded] = useState(false);
 useEffect(() => {
   async function importFonts() {
     await Font.loadAsync({
    'openSans-bold': require('../assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
    'openSans-bold-italic': require('../assets/fonts/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf'),
    'openSans-extra-bold': require('../assets/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf'),
    'openSans-extra-bold-italic': require('../assets/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf'),
    'openSans-italic': require('../assets/fonts/OpenSans-Italic.ttf'),
    'openSans-light': require('../assets/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf'),
    'openSans-light-italic': require('../assets/fonts/OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf'),
    'openSans-regular': require('../assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'),
    'openSans-semi-bold': require('../assets/fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf'),
    'openSans-semi-bold-italic': require('../assets/fonts/OpenSans-SemiboldItalic.ttf'),
  });
}
importFonts().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
setAssetsLoaded(true);
}, []);
 if (assetsLoaded) {
return (
  <>
    <IconRegistry icons={EvaIconsPack} />
    <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={{ ...eva.light, ...theme }} customMapping={mapping}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <TabNavigator />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ApplicationProvider>
  </>
);
}
  return (
     <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={{ ...eva.light, ...theme }}>
       <Text>Loading</Text>
     </ApplicationProvider>
  );
};
```

I am also getting a `Property 'components' is missing in type ...` on `customMapping={mapping}` I don't know if that relates to this problem.
I've reviewed all of the SO questions and github issues related to this, nothing helped.
I've also ran `expo r -c`, deleted `node_modules` and ran `yarn install` again, nothing helped, I am quite lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your error I assume you are using Expo.
Expo docs say this about loading fonts:

> Since your fonts won't be ready right away, it is generally a good practice to not render anything until the font is ready.
>   (link to this part of the docs [here](https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-custom-fonts/#using-the-apploading--component))

It's a good idea to use an [AppLoading](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading/) component in your app. It should not affect the visual aspects of your app, because it works in the "backstage".

So your component might look a little bit like this: 
(sorry it's not in TypeScript, I don't have any experience with TSX)

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { AppLoading, Asset, Font, Icon } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoadingComplete: false,
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete && !this.props.skipLoadingScreen) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
          onError={this._handleLoadingError}
          onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>The app is loaded, yay!</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  _loadResourcesAsync = async () => {
    return Promise.all([
      Asset.loadAsync([
        require('./assets/images/robot-dev.png'),
        require('./assets/images/robot-prod.png'),
      ]),
      Font.loadAsync({
        'space-mono': require('./assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
        'taviraj': require('./assets/fonts/Taviraj-Regular.ttf'),
      }),
    ]);
  };

  _handleLoadingError = error => {
    // In this case, you might want to report the error to your error
    // reporting service, for example Sentry
    console.warn(error);
  };

  _handleFinishLoading = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoadingComplete: true });
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: primaryColor,
  },
});
```